# OpenXML Find Variables within Word doc and replace them

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml, openxml-sdk

I need to search a document for strings enclosed in <>. So if the application finds the variable  within the document, it replaces that variable with DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString(). For instance:

```
string filename = "C:\\Temp\\" + appNum + "_ReceiptOfApplicationLtr.docx";
if (File.Exists((string)filename))
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filename, true))
    {
        var body = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
        foreach (var text in body.Descendants<Text>())
        {
            if (text.Text == "<TodaysDate>")
            {
                text.Text = text.Text.Replace("<TodaysDate>", DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
            }
        }
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
        {
            sw.Write(filename);
        }
    }
}
```

Well when it searches the Descendants Text, it finds the first <, then TodaysDate, finally >. The issue being it won't find the string `<TodaysDate>`. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone still struggling with this - you can check out this library

https://github.com/antonmihaylov/OpenXmlTemplates

With it instead of searching for special tags in the text (because of the problems specified in the comment of Thomas Barnekow), you add a Content control in the document and in the tag name of the content control you specify the name of the variable you want to replace.

You can then feed JSON data or a regular C# dictionary object and the text will get replaced.

Note - I am the maker of that library, but i have no financial gain from it - it is open sourced and under active development (and always looking for contributors!)

Answer (score 3):

Open XML can store text in different `text` tags inside the same run. What I would do if I were you is just find the `Run` where your string is stored and use the `InnerText` property to find all the text inside that run.
For example:

```
Run runToFind = body.Descendants<Run>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Innertext.Contains("<TodaysDate>");
```

Then you can replace the `Run` with another one:

```
runToFind.Parent.Replace(new Run(new Text(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())),runToFind);
```

Comment: This answer is not correct if you want this to work with documents produced by or edited with Microsoft Word, for example. While the standard allows a `w:r` element (`Run` instance) to contain more than one `w:t` element (`Text` instance), a `w:r` element typically contains at most one `w:t` element. Thus, if a text is split across multiple `w:t` elements, it is most likely also split across multiple `w:r` elements. Have a look at markup produced by Microsoft Word to confirm this.